Encoding issues within WebKitGtk WebView
I have a C GTK project in which i'm trying to use WebKitGtk. Unfortanatly I have come acrros an issue with one my external JS script, it gives me this error: "SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u2118' ". I have tried to look into encoding and such but I have found no fixes (i have confirmed via webkit_settings_get_default_charset that it uses UTF-8). If you have any ideas feel free too share cause i dont know what to try next...
Here are some info about my configurations:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
GTK: 3.18.9
WebKitGtk: 4.0.37
I tried uing webkit_settings_set_default_charset, added  into my HTML, tried having the JS allready downloaded and be downloaded by the web page.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The error message "SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u2118'" suggests that there's an invalid character (in this case, U+2118, which is the "SCRIPT CAPITAL P" character) in your JavaScript file. This issue could be caused by a number of reasons such as incorrect file encoding, a typo, or corruption in the JavaScript file.
Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:
1. Check File Encoding
Even though you mentioned that the encoding is set to UTF-8, it’s good to double-check that the JavaScript file is indeed saved with UTF-8 encoding.
You can use the file command to check the file encoding:
file your_script.js

Ensure the output indicates that the file is in UTF-8 encoding. If not, convert it to UTF-8 using tools like iconv:
iconv -f <current_encoding> -t utf-8 your_script.js -o your_script_utf8.js

2. Inspect the JavaScript File
Manually inspect the JavaScript file for any non-standard or invisible characters. You can use a text editor that supports viewing and editing in different encodings (like vim, nano, or a GUI editor).
You can also use tools like cat -v to visualize non-printable characters:
cat -v your_script.js

3. Re-download the JavaScript File
If the JavaScript file is being downloaded from an external source, it might be worth re-downloading it to ensure it hasn’t been corrupted.
4. Sanitize the JavaScript File
You can write a small script to sanitize your JavaScript file by removing non-UTF-8 characters. Here is an example using Python:
import re

def remove_non_utf8_chars(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
        content = file.read()
    
    sanitized_content = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', content)
    
    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(sanitized_content)

remove_non_utf8_chars('your_script.js')

5. Verify JavaScript Syntax
Ensure there are no syntax errors or typos in your JavaScript file. Sometimes, a misplaced character or typo can lead to such errors.
6. Use a Different Version of WebKitGtk
Since you are using an older version of WebKitGTK (4.0.37), it might be worthwhile to try a newer version if possible. There might be bug fixes or improvements in handling character encodings in newer versions.
Example Code in C (Using WebKitGTK)
Here’s a simple example of how you might load a web page with a JavaScript file in a WebKitGTK application:
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 600);
    
    WebKitWebView *web_view = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), GTK_WIDGET(web_view));

    WebKitSettings *settings = webkit_web_view_get_settings(web_view);
    webkit_settings_set_default_charset(settings, "UTF-8");

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    webkit_web_view_load_uri(web_view, "file:///path/to/your/local/file.html");

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

In the HTML file, ensure you specify UTF-8 encoding in the meta tag:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="your_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</body>
</html>

Following these steps should help you identify and fix the issue with the invalid character in your JavaScript file.
